# Slow Responce in JSON RPC

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsurlconnection, json-rpc

a Strange Case :

I'm using [DSJSONRPC](https://github.com/dbowen/Demiurgic-JSON-RPC%E2%80%8E) to do my client server communication in my App, I've noticed that the Request is sent fast but the Response suffer slowness although the web services on web work perfect and fast. What can be the problem ???

Comment: How long of a list do you want?

Comment: sorry i didn't catch that, can you explain more

Comment: @HotLicks: `@`OXXY means that you've asked a really vague, broad question to which there could be thousands of different answers. I'll add that you've also shown no code, nor what your expectations are of that code, or even what you've tried to change it.